# A viscosity unit

Tags: units, viscosity

Does the viscosity unit "$\mathrm{ps}$" exist or is it a misprint and refers to poise "$\mathrm{P}$"? Thank you

A liquid of $0.014\,\mathrm{ps}$ viscosity and $1.4\,\mathrm{g/cm^3}$ density circulates through a $3.14\,\mathrm{cm^2}$ section pipe with a flow rate of $0.352\,\mathrm{liters/s}$. Determine the Reynolds number of the flow and decide if the liquid is flowing in laminar or turbulent regime. Sun: $Re = 22415$; turbulent regime

Comment: ... and this quote comes from the source ... ?

Comment: As a matter of typesetting conventions, units should be set in roman type.

Comment: And while I was in there I also adjusted the spacing between value and unit to a thin space `\,` instead of `~`, though that is less standardized.

Comment: Wikipedia-fu for you: [viscosity#unit section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Units) leads to [poise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poise_(unit)) which states *cps* is an alternative abbreviation for *centipoise* which is then obvious that ps is indeed poise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778/25301).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two common units for viscosity are the [poise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poise_(unit)) (symbol $\rm{P}$) and the [Pascal second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_viscosity,_%CE%BC) (symbol $\rm{Pa.s}$). The poise is the cgs unit while the Pascal second is the SI unit.

Given that the question appears to be using the cgs system I would guess that *ps* is being used as an abbreviation for *poise*.